# coded ui ddt tfs connection string

Tags: tfs, coded-ui-tests

This should be a super easy question though I have been unable to find specific details in my search. A coded ui test that is data drive from TFS has the following tag:

[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase)", "http://pdalm-prod-app1.rd.allscripts.com:8080/tfs/eehr", "784418", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

The second parameter, after the port, is ... what, precisely? tfs is a fixed string? The next is the project. What else  needs to be there to make the correct connection? I am not the config manager. Is the url the same as the web access? I would think not. Is there a place that I can easily find the uri to the data source?

Thanks helping the noob!

Answer (score 0):

Could be Test case Id

Test case id of the test case within MTM.  Test Case 42338

Example:

[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", TfsConnectionString, "42338", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

Comment: Yeah I totally checked the test case. An bunch. :) Low hanging fruit.

Answer (score 0):

The `/tfs/` part of the URL is a configuration option on the TFS server itself, much like port 8080. The path `/tfs/` and port 8080 are the defaults for new TFS servers.

Open up TFS Web Access and check the URL to confirm this part of the URL.